# problems with template friend of template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces, friend

I ran into what to me looks like an inconsistency of the c++ compiler. In the following example code

```
#include <vector>
namespace test {
  class A : std::vector<int>
  {
    template<typename F>
    friend void bar(A const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) f(i); }
    template<int K, typename F>
    friend void foo(A const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }
  };
}
int sum(test::A const&a)
{
  int s=0;
  foo<2>(a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );    // <-- error here
  bar   (a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );    // <-- but not here
  return s;
}
```

gcc (4.7.0, using std=c++11) complains about "`foo` was not declared in this scope" (and suggests `test::foo` as alternative), but happily compiles the usage of `bar` in the next line. Now both, `foo` and `bar` are injected into the namespace `test` via their `friend` declaration, so neither should really be present in the global namespace.

**Q1** Am I mistaken, or is this a new twist of c++11, or is gcc misbehaving?

Of course, the problem is avoided if I simply inject using directives into the global namespace. However, if I make `A` a template,

```
#include <vector>
namespace test {
  template<typename T>
  class A : std::vector<T>
  {
    template<typename F>
    friend void bar(A const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) f(i); }
    template<int K, typename F>
    friend void foo(A const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }
  };
}
using test::foo;          // does not avoid compilation error
using test::bar;          // does not avoid compilation error
int sum(test::A<int> const&a)
{
  int s=0;
  foo<2>(a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );
  bar   (a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );
  return s;
}
```

gcc complains again. Either (without the `using` directives) that "`foo` was not declared in this scope" (but again happily compiles `bar`, though does not suggest `test::foo`) or (with the `using` directive) that "`test::foo` has not been declared" (and the same for `test::bar`) at the point of the `using` directive.

**Q2** This looks to me like a compiler error, as neither with or without `using` directive can I call `test::foo`. Or perhaps I there is something about C++ that I missed?

Finally, I tried to move the friend definition outside the class as in

```
namespace test {
  template<typename T>
  class A : std::vector<int>
  {
    template<int K, typename F>
    friend void foo(A const&a, F f);
    template<typename F>
    friend void bar(A const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) f(i); }
  };

  template<int K, typename T, typename F>
  void foo(A<T> const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }

}
using test::foo;
```

when gcc again complains, this time claiming that `void test::foo(const test::A<T>&, F)` is used but never defined ... So **Q3** what's wrong?

Answers to any sub-question welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1:**

> Am I mistaken, or is this a new twist of c++11, or is gcc misbehaving?

No, this is normal behavior. From Paragraph 14.8.1/8 of the C++11 Standard:

> For simple function names, argument dependent lookup (3.4.2) applies even when the function name
>   is not visible within the scope of the call. This is because the call still has the syntactic form of a function
>   call (3.4.1). **But when a function template with explicit template arguments is used, the call does not have
>   the correct syntactic form unless there is a function template with that name visible at the point of the call**.
>   If no such name is visible, the call is not syntactically well-formed and argument-dependent lookup does not
>   apply. If some such name is visible, argument dependent lookup applies and additional function templates
>   may be found in other namespaces. [ Example:

```
namespace A {
    struct B { };
    template<int X> void f(B);
}
namespace C {
    template<class T> void f(T t);
}
void g(A::B b) {
    f<3>(b); // ill-formed: not a function call
    A::f<3>(b); // well-formed
    C::f<3>(b); // ill-formed; argument dependent lookup
    // applies only to unqualified names
    using C::f;
    f<3>(b); // well-formed because C::f is visible; then
    // A::f is found by argument dependent lookup
}
```

> —end example ]

---

**Q2:**

> This looks to me like a compiler error, as neither with or without using directive can I call test::foo. Or perhaps I there is something about C++ that I missed?

If your class becomes a class *template* which you never instantiate, then the compiler will never perform the second-phase name lookup which would occur when instantiating `A<>`, so it will it never find out that there are two `friend` functions declared in it.

If you introduced, for instance, an explicit instantiation of your template *before* the `using` declarations, you should see things changing:

```
template class test::A<int>;
```

Alternatively, you could just change the definition of `A` so that it only *declares*, and doesn't define, the two `friend` function templates, and provide an out-of-class definition for those function templates. Which is, I guess, what you actually tried to do. But...

**Q3:**

> gcc again complains, this time claiming that void test::foo(const test::A&, F) is used but never defined... So what's wrong?

The problem is that you are not declaring as friend the same function that you are later defining: notice, that the function you defined takes one additional argument (`T`). Fix your declaration, and you'll see the program compile:

```
namespace test 
{
    template<typename T>
    class A : std::vector<int>
    {
        template<int K, typename C, typename F>
        //              ^^^^^^^^^^  (can't use T here, it would shadow
        //                           the class's template parameter)
        friend void foo(A<C> const&a, F f);
    };

    template<int K, typename C, typename F>
    void foo(A<C> const&a, F f) 
    { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }
}

using test::foo; // Just don't remove this, or we will be back in Q1 ;-)
```

---

**CONCLUSION:**

Thus, after all the necessary modifications, this is how your program will look like:

```
#include <vector>

namespace test
{
    template<typename T>
    class A : std::vector<T>
    {
        template<typename F, typename C>
        friend void bar(A<C> const&a, F f);

        template<int K, typename F, typename C>
        friend void foo(A<C> const&a, F f);
    };

    template<typename F, typename C>
    void bar(A<C> const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) f(i); }

    template<int K, typename F, typename C>
    void foo(A<C> const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }
}

using test::foo;
using test::bar;

int sum(test::A<int> const& a)
{
    int s=0;
    foo<2>(a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );
    bar   (a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );

    return s;
}
```

Comment: "Should look like" is a bit too strong because the `using` might not be what the OP really wants - in some cases you really want ADL to happen and it's important to understand what it is and how it works.

Comment: @DanielFrey: I changed "should" into "will".

Comment: Also, you answer to Q2 is a bit strange as the compiler always *parses* the code. Anyway, your answer is quite helpful, so: +1

Comment: @DanielFrey: Unqualified names aren't checked during the first phase. I will make that more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem and the answer to your questions is called ADL and the rules for when it is applied. It's not new in C++11 and it's not a problem with GCC.

**Q1:** You have a parameter `a` of type `test::A` (in the first example), hence ADL (argument dependent lookup) looks for methods in namespace `test`, but *only for non-template calls*. This is why `foo<2>` (a template call) is not found and `bar` is.

**Q2:** Answered after Q3, see below.

**Q3:** Your function definition for `test::foo` does not define the function you declared as a friend of `test::A<T>`. Change it to

```
namespace test
{
  template<typename T>
  class A;

  template<int K, typename F,typename T>
  void foo(A<T> const&a, F f);

  template<typename T>
  class A : std::vector<int>
  {
    template<int K, typename F,typename U>
    friend void foo(A<U> const&a, F f);
    template<typename F>
    friend void bar(A const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) f(i); }
  };

  template<int K, typename F,typename T>
  void foo(A<T> const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }
}
using test::foo;
```

**Q2:** Similar to Q3, you can fix it like this:

```
#include <vector>
namespace test {
  template<typename T>
  class A;

  template<typename F,typename T>
  void bar(A<T> const&a, F f);
  template<int K, typename F,typename T>
  void foo(A<T> const&a, F f);

  template<typename T>
  class A : std::vector<T>
  {
    template<typename F,typename U>
    friend void bar(A<U> const&a, F f);
    template<int K, typename F,typename U>
    friend void foo(A<U> const&a, F f);
  };

  template<typename F,typename U>
  void bar(A<U> const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) f(i); }
  template<int K, typename F,typename U>
  void foo(A<U> const&a, F f) { for(auto i:a) if(i&K) f(i); }
}
using test::foo;
using test::bar;
int sum(test::A<int> const&a)
{
  int s=0;
  foo<2>(a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );
  bar   (a,[&s](int i) { s+=i; } );
  return s;
}
```

Andy already explained why your original example does not work.

Comment: uhm, `bar` is a template function.

Comment: @Walter. Right, edited. Also, I'll add some more details on Q2/Q3 since there are a few more details I guess...

Comment: I tried that (**Q3**), but got `too many template-parameter-lists`

Comment: @Walter: The original was not correct (after the edit, it is). See my answer also for Q2.